# Is it safe to remove the space between 'content' and 'charset'?

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags, minify

I already [searched](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) for a while, and I failed to find any references on whether it is safe/possible to remove the space here:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;`this space`charset=UTF-8" />`

I also tried compressing the script on 'Aggressive Minimization', but they don't seem to remove it.

I see that they removed the space on [this website example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp). But I can't rely on that kind of websites any more.

Comment: If it is quoted, then I don't think it matters.  However, if it is **not** quoted, then it got split into two different attributes (`content` and `charset`).  However, since it happens so much, every browser on the market can grok a separate `charset` attribute on `http-equiv`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The specification of media types, RFC 2045, does not require a space. Neither does it prohibit a space; this is more implicit, since RFC 2045 refers to the extended BNF as defined in RFC 822, which clarifies this in clause 3.4.2. WHITE SPACE:

“Note:  In structured field bodies, multiple linear space ASCII
               characters  (namely  HTABs  and  SPACEs) are treated as
               single spaces and may freely surround any  symbol.   In
               all header fields, the only place in which at least one
               LWSP-char is REQUIRED is at the beginning of  continuation lines in a folded field.”

According to HTML5 drafts, the specific kind of `meta` tags under discussion can be written in the following more compact form, on the grounds that user agents have long recognized it:

```
<meta charset=UTF-8>
```

If XHTML serialization is needed, use

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

This is more readable and safer (fewer possibilities of mistyping when you type it by hand).

Answer (score 1):

there is no harm in that as long as there is the semicolon ";" after `text/html`...

Comment: do you have anything that supports that?

Comment: @ajax333221, yes out of my experience and lots of testing :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there used to be a [bug in Exchange Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913856/problem-consuming-exchange-web-service-2010-with-jax-ws-metro) that required the space, but browsers in general don't care.